# Inline style not working in draft-js convertFromHTML

Tags: reactjs, rtf, draftjs

I am using draft-js for RTF field. I wanted to set some HTMl content to draftjs. when I am trying to set normal HTML without any style attribute it is working fine but when I am passing HTML with **style** attribute or any other attribute then it drops the attribute.

```
    const sampleMarkup =
  '<div style="color:red">red text</div>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ><br />' +
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>';

const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
);

this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
};
```

Any one having workaround for this please update.. thanx in advance

Answer (score -5):

Try `!important` tag for your inline style.

```
<div style="color:red">red text</div>
```

Replace to like this.

```
<div style="color:red !important;">red text</div>
```